# audio_service flutter package does not start

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use the audio_service package to allow background controls for my podcast playing app.  The service does not start. When I call `AudioService.start()`, nothing is ever returned (I'm `await`ing this function and trying to print a statement after this returns, but it never returns. Also, when I first attempt to play an item, it will correctly evaluate `AudioService.running` to false and then try to start the AudioService (hanging on the `start()` function). When I hit play a second time, it will evaluate `AudioService.running` as true (even though the start function never returned) and will then throw this error:

```
E/flutter ( 8726): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.invokeMethod(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$Result)' on a null object reference, null, null)
E/flutter ( 8726): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:572:7)
E/flutter ( 8726): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:161:18)
E/flutter ( 8726): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8726): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:12)
E/flutter ( 8726): #3      AudioService.play (package:audio_service/audio_service.dart:895:20)
```

Here is my code which calls the start function:

```
    if(AudioService.running) {
      print('playing audio service: ${AudioService.running}');
      AudioService.play();
    } else {
      MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem(
        id: newPostPod.audioUrl,
        title: newPostPod.titleTextString(),
        artist: newPostPod.subtitleTextString(),
      );
      print('starting audio service');
      bool started = await AudioService.start(
        backgroundTaskEntrypoint: _backgroundTaskEntrypoint,
        params: {'mediaItem': mediaItem.toJson()},
      );
      print('audio service started');
      if(AudioService.running) {
        print('starting to play via media service');
        AudioService.playMediaItem(mediaItem);
      } else {
        print('Audio Service not yet started: $started');
      }
    }
```

The code for the background task entrypoint (which is outside of any other class, as it wasn't working inside a class I had read in another issue that it had to be top-level):

```
_backgroundTaskEntrypoint() {
  AudioServiceBackground.run(() => PlayerTask());
}
```

Lastly, it doesn't appear any of the code within my `onStart` in my BackgroundAudioTask is running (as print statements at the top of my onStart are not being run). So I'm not sure what's happening here. It isn't give me a clear error or really any hint of where to start debugging audio_service.

Comment: have you called AudioService.connect();? or wrapped with audio service widget? if you didn't you need to do that first

Comment: Ahh, I thought I had the AudioServiceWidget included, but missed it. Thank you! Now I just have to get the buttons to work haha, none of the notifcation buttons trigger their functions.

Comment: Sounds great Kyle so did this solve your problem? if it did let me know I will post it as a solution so that others also might refer if necessary.

Comment: Yes, this did solve this issue! Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome kyle 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `AudioService.connect();` before starting the service will solve the error.

Answer (score 1):

For me `AudioService.start()` would freeze until I added the `WAKE_LOCK` and `FOREGROUND_SERVICE` permissions to the AndroidManifest.xml file per the audio_service README file.